# how to add checkbox in ruby on rails and fetch it value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

My code:

```
Hobby:-<%= f.check_box :hobby %>
<%= label :hobby_cricket, 'cricket' %>
<%= f.check_box :hobby %>
<%= label :check_box_hockey, 'hockey' %>
```

I had tried using the below code:
    <%= f.input :hockey, :as => :boolean, input_html: {checked:   false} %>
    <%= f.input :cricket, :as => :boolean, input_html: {checked:   false} %>
My output using above code is 1 or 0 but 
I want my output as cricket or hockey

Can anybody please help me??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you would like to have a checkbox value like "hockey" or "cricket" instead of 0 or 1.

You can do it as follows:

```
<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:class => your_class_name }, "hockey", "cricket" %>
```

Comment: I have tried your code but getting error as                              undefined method `merge' for "hockey":String